# ¿Why can't I concatenate two arrays in this query handler?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, server

I am trying to merge arrays from a request to already existing arrays in a MongoDB database. When I printed the output of the request, the arrays did not merge. What seems to be the issue here?

```
router.post('/add-publication-data', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const publication = await Publications.findOne({ _id: req.body._id });
        publication.toObject();
        publication.additionalauthors.concat(req.body.additionalauthors)
        publication.students.concat(req.body.students)
        console.log(publication.students)
        publication.institutions.concat(req.body.institutions)
        publication.keywords.concat(req.body.keywords)
        publication.highlights.concat(req.body.highlights)
        publication.save()
            .then(
                data => {
                    res.json(data);
                })
            .catch(e => {
                res.json({
                    message: e
                });
            });
    } catch (err) { console.log(err); res.json({ message: err }) };
});
```

Comment: `publication.students = publication.students.concat(req.body.students)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### concat() method

Your result is the expected behavior of `concat` method. From [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

> The concat() method is used to merge two or more arrays. This method
> does not change the existing arrays, but instead returns a new array.

You will need to assign the result back to have the merged array, change from:

```
publication.additionalauthors.concat(req.body.additionalauthors)
```

to:

```
publication.additionalauthors = publication.additionalauthors.concat(req.body.additionalauthors)
```

#### push() method

Another solution is to use `push` method

> The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and
> returns the new length of the array.

```
publication.additionalauthors.push(...req.body.additionalauthors)
```